# How to increment an Integer Column in flask + sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, database, flask, sqlalchemy

This is my first time working with Python, Flask and SQL (or even making a backend in general). I am trying to make a dashboard for stock portofolios. Right now I'm trying to make it that if a user adds a stock that is already present in his 'portofolio' it should increment the value by the amount the user entered, however it just keeps making new rows of the information the user entered.

This is my WTForms stock form:

```
class StockForm(FlaskForm):
    stockname = StringField('Stock', validators=[DataRequired()])
    amount = IntegerField('Amount', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Save Portofolio')
```

This is my Stock model:

```
class Stock(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    stockname = db.Column(db.String, index=True)
    amount = db.Column(db.Integer)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
```

and my User model:

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    stocks = db.relationship('Stock', backref='author', lazy='dynamic')
```

And this is the 'Add stock' route:

```
@app.route('/stock', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def stock():
form = StockForm()
if form.validate_on_submit():
    user = current_user
    stock = Stock(stockname=form.stockname.data, amount=form.amount.data, author=current_user)    
    check_stock = user.stocks.filter_by(stockname=stock.stockname).first()
    if check_stock is None
        db.session.add(stock)
        db.session.commit()
    else:
        check_stock.amount = check_stock.amount + stock.amount
        db.session.commit()
return render_template('stock.html', title='Add stock', form=form)
```

This is output I get of Stock.query.all() after I submit stockname='AAPL' and amount = 1 in my form the first time:

```
[Stock AAPL:2]
```

Which should be [Stock AAPL:1].
The second time I do this I get:

```
[Stock AAPL:1, Stock AAPL:2]
```

I want this to output:

```
[Stock AAPL:2]
```

Comment: check if you are getting the value of 'stock.amount'.

Comment: yes I am, I think the problem is that ''if check_stock is None'' is not correct